# Where to check what apps I have purchased

Tags: google-play-store, google

I got a statement from my bank and I have 2 transactions I do not know what they are.

> Google *E-Commerce Ltd GOOGLE.COM of 15.99

Normally I have a text, which indicates what app or service I have purchased. But these positions are simply don't have that information.

What is it? How to check what I have purchased in Google so far?

Comment: There should be an email saying "Thank you for your purchase of Ross's Brilliant Android Game" and the price etc etc sent to your Gmail, you could search that? Also your apps list will show anything that is purchased as below. Edit: I haven't made a brilliant game by the way, I'm not shilling anything! Edit 2: I haven't made a crap game either!

Comment: Not too many apps cost that much. Have you been buying any movies, music, or books?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think what you want is the [My Orders](https://play.google.com/store/account) page.

This is reachable from the Play Store web site under the "gear" menu in the upper right.

I see all of the things I've purchased from Google Play, including apps, music, etc.

---

For what it's worth, there does *not* appear to be a way to get a list of your orders from within the Play Store app. However, I do see a list of transactions in my Google Wallet app, although admittedly they're not all necessarily from the Play Store.

Comment: Thats probably a better answer than mine. Thats what I get for usually using freebie apps ;)

Comment: I feel this is the best answer because it includes *all* items, not just apps, that Google would bill you for - thus matching the transaction data in the question.

Comment: Me either. I just went to the site and started looking around.

Comment: Wow it's good to find this, some of the rubbish I have forked money over for is surprising. I have bought some real rubbish! Good to have a record in one place.

Answer (score 3):

Try the app [Purchased Apps](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.azefsw.purchasedapps).

> You can now browse and install your previous application purchases. It
>   shows only applications that you purchased, you don't have to dig
>   through hundreds of free apps anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Your Google Wallet shows all the transactions you made within Google’s websites. Since it’s your bank statement that shows a payment to google, it could be a range of things you paid for.

Visit wallet.google.com and in the transactions tab you will find all the purchases with name, date and value. When you click the transaction it shows you what you purchased, and even the credit card you used.

Comment: While the Play Store requires Google Wallet, Google Wallet can be used to purchase other things, so all the transactions listed there may not all be from the Play Store, and even then may not list exactly what was purchased. In any event, can you expand your answer, perhaps, with exactly the steps one would use to see previous transactions?

Comment: I mean, even though it lists all purchases, since it's his bank statement that's showing it, it could have been something else. Since all you purchase through Google appears on the wallet, it could be simpler to go there, because it shows everything. Also, sorry for the short answer, I'll elaborate better next time.

Comment: Don't wait until "next time". Go ahead and [edit] it now. This could be turned into an excellent answer.

Answer (score 1):

https://play.google.com/apps should show all the apps you have purchased under my apps. You'd probably have to work out which one of those apps is the one you're thinking about though

Comment: This one also includes the FREE apps.